# Установил ssl letsencrypt сертификат через root, теперь не могу перезапускать сервис nginx через обычного пользователя sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

В общем установил сертификат через пользователя root с помощью certbot. В конфиг nginx прописались следующие настройки:

```
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = example.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name example.ru www.example.ru;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Через root все работает - nginx -t показывает successful.
Но через обычного пользователя user с правами sudo при выполнений команды nginx -t, я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
[warn] 236559#236559: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
[emerg] 236559#236559: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ru/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ru/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib)
```

По ошибке понятно, что недостаточно прав для чтения файла с сертификатом.
Я выдал права на директорию etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ru/ с помощью chown user, но файлы все так же остаются на правах root.
Мне теперь каждый раз приходится подключаться через root, чтобы перезапустить сервис nginx.
Подскажите пожалуйста решение.

Comment: какую команду вы выполняете от пользователя (не root) `sudo nginx -t` или `nginx -t`?

Comment: Не готов сказать что именно, но возможно, что-то с принадлежностью к группам.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Если запускать через sudo, то все работает.